# How can I make my Rust function more generic & efficient?

Tags: performance, generics, rust, idioms

I have a function that works, but is more specialized than I'd like and has some inefficiencies, I'd like to fix that.

The working but flawed function:

```
fn iter_to_min<T>(i:T) -> i64 where T:Iterator<Item=String>{
    i.collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|s|s.split_whitespace())
        .map(str::trim)
        .map(str::parse::<i64>)
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .min()
        .expect("No min found.")
}
```

The reasons I dislike this implementation are:

- `i64` is hard coded and I'd like to reuse this function for `u64` and possibly other return types
- it collects it's input just to iterate over it immediately which is inefficient (heap allocation for no reason)
- the closure passed to `flat_map` might not be optimized away by LLVM in all cases

and the closest I could get to my ideal function:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn iter_to_min<T,U>(i:T) -> U where T:Iterator<Item=String>,U: Ord+FromStr{
    i.flat_map(str::split_whitespace)
        .map(str::trim)
        .map(str::parse::<U>)
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .min()
        .expect("No min found.")
}
```

The problems I am seeing are:

- the argument passed to `str::split_whitespace` is a `String` and won't coerce to a `str`
- the argument passed to `str::split_whitespace` isn't known to live long enough
- `Result::unwrap` doesn't complains that the trait `core::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for the type `<U as core::str::FromStr>::Err`

I think that with clever lifetime notation and Trait requirements at least two of those could be fixed, and who knows maybe there's a way to go three for three.

Example code using some suggested fixes:

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn iter_to_min<T,U>(i:T) -> U where T:Iterator<Item=String>,U: Ord+FromStr, U::Err: Debug{
    i.collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|s|s.split_whitespace())
        .map(str::trim)
        .map(str::parse::<U>)
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .min()
        .expect("No min found.")
}

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<_> = std::env::args().skip(1).collect();
    let m:i64 = if a.is_empty() {
        let s = std::io::stdin();
        let m = iter_to_min(s.lock().lines().map(Result::unwrap));
        m
    }else{
        iter_to_min(a.into_iter())
    };
    println!("{}", m);
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could post a complete, minimal example that I could paste into a file locally to get up and running :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do what you want when keeping both the genericity and the absence of allocations. The reason is that you need someone to own your string data, but if `flat_map(str::split_whitespace)` is performed over an iterator of owned strings, then there is no one to keep these owned strings anymore because `str::split_whitespace` only borrows the string it is called on. However, if you "push" the ownership up the call chain, you won't be able to be fully generic and accept owned strings by value.

Therefore, there are two solutions: to precollect the entire iterator to a `Vec<String>` (or to transform the items yielded by `split_whitespace()` to owned strings separately and collect them to a `Vec` again), or to accept an iterator of references.

Here is the most generic version I could come up with of the first solution:

```
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn iter_to_min<S, T, U>(i: T) -> U
    where S: Into<String>,
          T: IntoIterator<Item=S>,
          U: Ord + FromStr,
          U::Err: Debug
{
    i.into_iter()
        .map(Into::into)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|s| s.split_whitespace())
        .map(str::parse::<U>)
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .min()
        .expect("No min found")
}
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c06d36229426d9f213da21b09c96ec20&version=stable&backtrace=0))

It is basically the same as your first one but more generic. Also note that you don't need to trim the parts of the string after `split_whitespace()` - the latter will make sure that the parts of the string do not have spaces at their sides. `Into<String>` bound allows one to pass both `&str` and `String` iterators, and in the latter case no extra copies will be done.

Alternatively, you can split each line into owned strings separately:

```
fn iter_to_min<S, T, U>(i: T) -> U
    where S: AsRef<str>,
          T: IntoIterator<Item=S>,
          U: Ord + FromStr,
          U::Err: Debug
{
    i.into_iter()
        .flat_map(|s| s.as_ref().split_whitespace().map(String::from).collect::<Vec<_>>())
        .map(|s| s.parse::<U>())
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .min()
        .expect("No min found")
}
```

Here we only need to obtain a `&str`s from iterator items, not `String`s, so I used `AsRef<str>`. However, each line must not only be converted to a sequence of `String`s; this sequence must be collected into a vector for exactly the same reason described above - otherwise there would be no one to keep the original values of type `S` from destruction.

But it *is* possible to avoid the `.map(String::from).collect::<Vec<_>>()` if you are willing to lose some genericity, though. This is the second solution I've mentioned above. We can accept an iterator over references:

```
fn iter_to_min<'a, S: ?Sized, T, U>(i: T) -> U
    where S: AsRef<str> + 'a,
          T: IntoIterator<Item=&'a S>,
          U: Ord + FromStr,
          U::Err: Debug
{
    i.into_iter()
        .map(AsRef::as_ref)
        .flat_map(str::split_whitespace)
        .map(|s| s.parse::<U>())
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .min()
        .expect("No min found")
}
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f03d714988e34c97ab314c54376e9d56&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Roughly speaking, now `S` values are owned by someone else, and their lifetime is bigger than the scope of `iter_to_min()`, so you need neither to transform each part to `String` nor to collect the entire split result to a `Vec<String>`. However, you won't be able to pass a `Vec<String>` to this function; you will be able to pass `vec.iter()`, however:

```
let v: Vec<String> = vec!["0".into(), "1".into()];
iter_to_min(v.iter())
```

In all these examples I've changed `Iterator` to `IntoIterator` - this is almost always what you want to use instead of just `Iterator`. It allows you, for example, to pass collections to such functions directly. Second, I've added `U::Err: Debug` condition, which is necessary for `Result::unwrap` to work. And finally, to fix the problem with "String not coercing to &str` you can always use explicit closures and method syntax which would do this coercion for you.

Answer (score 3):

A solution without extra allocations

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn iter_to_min<T, U>(i: T) -> Option<U>
    where T: Iterator<Item = String>,
          U: Ord + FromStr
{
    i.filter_map(|string| {
            string.split_whitespace()
                .map(str::trim)
                .map(str::parse::<U>)
                .filter_map(Result::ok)
                .min()
        })
        .min()
}
```